# Is it possible to derive the declared function from DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS command?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, typedef

Can you derive the function declaration from the output of the following command DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS command ? I ran this command as follows: **DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS libinfinityhook.lib** and got the following from the dump:

`IfhInitialize@@YAJP6AXIPEAPEAX@Z@Z (long __cdecl IfhInitialize(void (__cdecl*)(unsigned int,void * *)))`

What would the function declaration of the above output be ? Perhaps something like the following:

```
NTSTATUS IfhInitialize(
_In_ INFINITYHOOKCALLBACK InfinityHookCallback);
```

assuming the following typedef:

```
typedef void (__fastcall * INFINITYHOOKCALLBACK)(_In_ unsigned int SystemCallIndex, _Inout_ void** SystemCallFunction);
```

Comment: You can use `undname.exe` to view the undecorated name.  q.v. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=msvc-160

Comment: @Eljay If you can post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio comes with a utility called [`undname.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=msvc-160) which will reverse most decorated names into *undecorated* names.

GNU Binutils has [`c++filt`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html) which will do the same for GCC name mangling.

LLVM has [`llvm-cxxfilt`](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cxxfilt.html) the symbol name demangler, which is compatible with GNU Binutils `c++filt` because LLVM and GCC use the same name mangling scheme.

On a related note, in process, Boost [`demangle`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html) allows undecorating symbol names from the `typeid` `name()`.  Keeping in mind that the `typeid` `name()` is not dictated by the C++ standard, rather is compiler specific.  So it is not portable, and not suitable for cross-platform serialization/deserialization.  Alas.